# jQuery mobile setting selected attribute on dynamically generated select menu

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

I'm dynamically generating the content of a select menu in jQuery mobile, and I'm trying to set the selected attribute on the first option in the menu, but it doesn't seem to want to work.  Here's my AJAX response:

```
request.done(function(response){
    $('#selectCat option').remove();
    if(response.categories.length != 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < response.categories.length; i++) {
            $('<option name="' + response.categories[i].cat_name
            + '" id="' + response.categories[i].cat_id_PK + '">' 
            + response.categories[i].cat_name + ' - &#36;' 
            + response.categories[i].cat_amount + '</option>')
            .appendTo("#selectCat");   
        }
    };
    if(response.recurring.length != 0) {
        for(var i = 0; i < response.recurring.length; i++) {
            $('<option name="' + response.recurring[i].cat_name + '" id="'
            + response.recurring[i].cat_id_PK + '">' 
            + response.recurring[i].cat_name + ' - &#36;' 
            + response.recurring[i].cat_amount + '</option>').appendTo("#selectCat1");
        }
    };
    $('#selectCat option:first-child').attr('selected', true)
    .siblings('option').removeAttr('selected');
});
```

That code generates the following when viewed in Chrome dev tools:

```
<option name="Grooming" id="109" selected="selected">Test - $40.00</option>
<option name="Test" id="110">Test - $50.00</option></select>
```

It seems like I wouldn't need to refresh the menu, since that's what the AJAX request is doing, but other questions on SO point to that as the culprit.

Comment: Define your 'doesn't seem to want to work'. The HTML is there and supposed to be correct(?), so my guess is your browser is not updating the selected item?

Comment: Hmmm... i can image it is that your browser is not updating the select element as you are only changing the selected attribute of one of the options. It does not involve the element to actually SHOW that item as being selected. can you try $("#selectCat").prop("selectedIndex",1); instead?

Comment: You need to _refresh_ selectmenu after any changes. `$('#selectCat').selectmenu("refresh");`

Comment: @Omar - that did the trick.  I had tried a different version of that attempting to update the menu before, and it didn't work.  thanks for the help!  if you make it an answer I'll give you credit for it.

Comment: @hyphen glad it worked for you. check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706764/jquery-mobile-not-displaying-correct-selected-item-in-list/20706846#20706846