# Select first Option in Select element with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've read a few posts on how to select the first Option in an HTML Select element with jQuery, but I can't seem to get it working on a jQuery mobile page.

Select element:

```
<select id="myList">
    <option value="" selected>Select a List</option>
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

Script I'm invoking to select first Option:

```
$("#myList").val($("#myList option:first").val());
```

I'm not trying to get the value of the first option in the select element, I'm actually trying to select it.

Is there something else I need to do in order to get this to work on a jQuery mobile page?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you mean to get the value of the first option, or to get the first option element object, or to make the first option in that select box selected?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I meant "make the first option in that box selected." Basically, if the Use selects Item 1, then onChange I redirect them to another "page" on my jQuery mobile site. Then, when they click the back button in the menu, I bring them back to the "page" with the Select on it, and want the "Select a List" option selected. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, just answered, let me know if that works for you

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery mobile not displaying correct selected item in list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706764/jquery-mobile-not-displaying-correct-selected-item-in-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to use `selectmenu("refresh")`.

> **refresh update the custom select:** This is used to update the custom
>   select to reflect the native select element's value. If the number of
>   options in the select are different than the number of items in the
>   custom menu, it'll rebuild the custom menu. Also, if you pass a true
>   argument you can force the rebuild to happen.

```
//refresh value         
$('select').selectmenu('refresh');

//refresh and force rebuild
$('select').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

[**source**](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/forms/selects/methods.html)

**html**

```
<select id="myList">
    <option value="" selected>Select a List</option>
    <option value="1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

**js**

```
$("#myList").val($("#myList option:eq(1)").val());
$("#myList").selectmenu("refresh");
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/nqgka2qz/2/)

Comment: This is perfect. It was the refresh that I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To make the first option in the list selected use this:

```
$("#myList option:eq(0)").attr("selected","selected");
```

But in your case I think that first option is selected by default, so if you meant the option with value="1" than use this:

```
$("#myList option:eq(1)").attr("selected","selected");
```

---

**UPDATE:**

If you have the option value, you can also use this:

```
$("#myList option[value='2']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Answer (score -1):

Please correct me if I am not getting th problem correctly. If you just want to get the value of option selected you can simply get it By

```
$("#myList").val();
```

Hope this be of some help

Happy Learning :)

Comment: The OP is not trying to get the value. Also, your solution will not work as your selector is incorrect.